# Logarithmic contour plotting color - matplotlib

Tags: python, colors, contour, logarithm, imshow

I've got a 2D array which I have plotted as a contour plot with matplotlib using the following:

```
ax = plt.subplot(331)
im = plt.imshow(list1[1], aspect = 'auto', extent = [mdotmin, mdotmax, sigmin, sigmax], vmin = lmin, vmax = lmax)
cp = plt.contour(mdot, sig, list1[1], levels )
```

where 'list1[0]' is the 2D array of values, and 'mdot' and 'sig' are 1D arrays for the x and y axes.
This seems to work OK, but I want to increase the ranges of sig and dot significantly, so I have taken logarithms of these values (e.g. mdotlog = np.log10(mdot)), and plotted these.  I now have the code snippet:

```
ax = plt.subplot(331)
im = plt.imshow(list1[1], aspect = 'auto', extent = [mdotlogmin, mdotlogmax, siglogmin, siglogmax], vmin = lmin, vmax = lmax)
cp = plt.contour(mdotlog, siglog, list1[1], levels )
```

The contour lines seem correct, but the colors from imshow aren't scaled to the logs, and I'm unsure how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: I've still not solved this.  Is there any additional information I could provide that would help towards finding a solution?

Comment: It'd be helpful to have mock data which demonstrates the problem you're having. You may have to specify origin='lower' in your call to imshow().